# Get checkout url of cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, url, extension, checkout

guys.

I am developing an extension for the cartthrob addon.
I'd like to get the url of checkout page in ext.myaddon.php.
How can I get this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific "checkout page" in CartThrob. A checkout form can be placed on any -- and as many -- templates as the developer would like. Therefore the best thing would be to determine what page the site owner wants to direct them to and let them set it in your extension settings or a tag parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But how can I determine the template-group and template in which the `checkout-form` includes.

Comment: There's not a consistent way to do that because a site can have a checkout on multiple templates; developers set their sites up in lots of different ways. You should have the URL you want to end up at/check for/etc entered as either a setting in your plugin or as a parameter on a tag you're making.